# Geometry Nodes - ignore local scale of the object

Tags: geometry-nodes

i am trying to create a setup that creates an object (a plane) at the camera's position. I am currently utilizing the "self Object" and "Object Info" node, to convert the object's position, scale and rotation to world space. So far, my setup works well:

[image]

The problem becomes apparent when the scaling of my object that holds the geometry nodes is non-uniform.

[image]

Now the orientation of the plane is wrong. My guess is, that i have to transform the rotation by taking the scale into account. I tried some methods, but node of them did work. So that's why i am asking you guys.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: The obvious question is, if you don't like how it looks when you scale it, then why are you scaling it?

Comment: Because I might want to animate the scale of the objects that is holding the geometry nodes

Comment: Can you describe exactly the end-effect you're looking for? Do you want the grid always to be oriented with the camera, irrespective of the rotation of the holding object? Do you want the grid always square? And.. out of interest, why is the grid part of the holding object,?

Comment: I am trying to create a grid that is exactly in front of the camera. The dimensions of the grid should be exactly in the 0 - 1 clip space of the camera. I want to use this grid to do further manipulations to the object. To be precise, I want to snap the objects vertices to the grid object. Sounds complicated, I know :)